# Add prefix to AUX file of included parts

Tags: compiling, include, auxiliary-files, multiple-files

I write course material for my students. Every chapter is in a different file. Some chapters are used in several classes, but in a different order. Say:

- ClassA.tex

  - including chapter-foo.tex as chapter 1
  - including chapter-bar.tex as chapter 2
  - including chapter-xyz.tex as chapter 3
- ClassB.tex

  - including chapter-abc.tex as chapter 1
  - including chapter-foo.tex as chapter 2
  - including chapter-bar.tex as chapter 3

Now, whenever I compile ClassA.tex or ClassB.tex, three AUX files are generated and all is fine. However, if I add a fourth chapter to class A's document and -- in order to save time -- use `\includeonly` so that the first three chapters can be skipped during compilation, this will get me wrong cross-references, if the last complete run has been done with ClassB.tex.

I am looking for a way to add some prefix to the AUX file's names, e.g. compiling chapter-foo.tex from ClassA.tex would use (and create, if necessary) a-chapter-foo.aux, wheres compiling it from ClassB.tex would use b-chapter-foo.aux.

Comment: I don't know of any package offering this and one would imho have to change quite a number of internal commands (and e.g. check side-effects on bibtex). What you could do is to use an intermediary layer: a `b-chapter-foo.tex` which contains only the line `\input{chapter-foo}`.

Comment: Indeed, a very simple way of achieving exactly what I want. Thank you very much. If you make it an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the auxiliary files of files included by `\ínclude` are used in the internal command `\@include` only. Patching the two occurrences of `#1.aux` solves the issue. The following patch prefixes `#1.aux` with the job name of the main document `\jobname`. It belongs to the preamble of the main files (`ClassA.tex` and `ClassB.tex`).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@include}{\@input{#1.aux}}{\@input{\jobname-#1.aux}}{}{%
  \errmessage{First patch of \noexpand\@include failed.}%
}
\patchcmd{\@include}{\@partaux #1.aux}{\@partaux\jobname-#1.aux}{}{%
  \errmessage{Second patch of \noexpand\@include failed.}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then, the auxiliary files for `chapter-???.tex` are no longer `chapter-???.tex` but `Class?-chapter-???.tex` (the single question mark is `A` or `B` and the question mark triple is `abc`, `bar`, `foo`,  or `xyz`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any package offering this and one would imho have to change quite a number of internal commands (and e.g. check side-effects on bibtex) to get it.

What you could do is to use an intermediary layer: create a `b-chapter-foo.tex` which contains only the line `\input{chapter-foo}`.